# Ubuntu 14.04 NIS Client connecting to a OpenSuse 13.1 NIS Server

Tags: ubuntu, opensuse, pam, nis

I've been trying this for the whole day, searching the internet but I just can not find the solution.

We're running a small server using OpenSuse 13.1 (NIS & NFS) at our office and it works perfectly with all clients also using OpenSuse. As I'm not a great fan of the distribution I've tried switching to Ubuntu, but our IT guy can't give me any support for this so I'm completely on my own.

I hadn't any problems setting up NFS and NIS. Everything works fine on paper.
yptest runs without errors.
ypmatch can match every user with the passwords and so on. 
I've read dozens of threads already and tried stuff like editing the pam.d/common-* files with libpam-unix2.so and such methods, but what I still can't get to work is actually logging in.

Whenever I try I get an authentication failure.

pam_unix(mdm:auth): conversation failed
pam_succeed_if(mdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "me"
pam_unix(mdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:20 ruser= rhost=  user="me"

The encryption on both systems is SHA512. Why doesn't it work? I just can't understand...

edit: I can, of course, provide further information if needed. But I can guarantee I've tried alle the mobst obvious approaches.
etc/shadow /group and /passwd are all correctly set up. /etc/nsswitch.conf was edited with some "nis" additions, etc.